# Disable Save As but not Save in Word 2010

Tags: vba, ms-word, save

I am looking to disable Save As in a Word 2010 file but still allow save. In other words I want users to be able to update the existing file but not create copies. I realize that this is impossible to truly do for people who know workarounds but for the general user I have successfully done this in Excel but am pretty new to word VBA.

When I add the following to a brand new document everything works as intended:

```
Sub FileSaveAs()
MsgBox "Copies of this file cannot be created. Please save changes in the original document." & _
, , "Copy Cannot be Created"
End Sub
```

My document has other macros for various command buttons but none of them involve saving the document (under original name or save as). There is also a macro running on open but that is 1 line going to a bookmark. When I try to "save as" in this document I get the message box as intended. When I try to "save" though things get strange: I get the save as dialogue (problem 1). Whether I try to save either under same name or other name the dialogue behaves as it normally would except it doesn't save and the dialogue box opens again automatically essentially creating an endless loop until I hit cancel (problem 2). I also intermittently get a "disk is full" warning pop-up after trying to save which I can dismiss but appears a few minutes later as long as he file is open (perhaps related to autosave?)

Since the macro works in the test file I assumed this strange behavior must be something elsewhere in my code but my document with the other macros saves normally as long as I don't include the save as code above so now I'm totally confused. Before I put up the rest of my code which is lengthy and for the reasons stated above I would not think impact things, I figured I'd ask this:
1. Is there any place other than my other command button macros that could be causing this behavior?
2. Is there a better method people recommend to achieve my ultimate goal of disabling save as but not save?

Thanks in advance for any advice you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Word application has a `DocumentBeforeSave` event. To enable application events I suggest to create a class module by the name of `ThisApplication` and paste the following code into it.

```
Option Explicit

    Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set App = Word.Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, _
                                   SaveAsUI As Boolean, _
                                   Cancel As Boolean)
    If SaveAsUI Then
        MsgBox "Please always use the ""Save"" command" & vbCr & _
               "to save this file.", _
               vbExclamation, "SaveAs is not allowed"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Add the following code to your `ThisDocument` module.

```
    Dim WdApp As ThisApplication

Private Sub Document_Open()
    Set WdApp = New ThisApplication
End Sub
```

You may add the `Set App = ...` line to your existing `Document_Open` procedure. After the WdApp variable has been initialised all application events will be received by the `ThisApplication` class where the `DocumentBeforeSave` event procedure is programmed not to allow `SaveAs`.

Of course, this is a blanket refusal for all documents. Therefore you may wish to add code to the procedure to limit the restriction to certain documents only. The proc receives the entire document object with all its properties, including Name, Path, FullName and built-in as well as custom properties. You can identify the files you wish to be affected by any of these.

Note that the `WdApp` variable will be erased in case of a program crash. If this happens the application events will no longer fire. It may be useful to know that application events occur before document events. This is if you wish to use the application's `DocumentOpen` event as well as or instead of the document's `Document_Open` event.

Comment: Variatus, Thank you very much for your help. Your code didn't work with the existing file but when I "recreated" the document (copy and pasted all content in the document and the code over to a new document) things worked much better (not sure why that would happen, and it makes me a little uneasy that whatever changed in the original file could change again at some point in the new file, but that's another matter).

Comment: I'm pretty sure its the initialisation of the WdApp variable which caused the problem. You can always run the Document_Open proc, which initialises the variable, with F5. You can also test for WdApp being active by writing a little sub with, `Debug.Print WdApp Is Nothing` in the ThisDocument sheet and run it with F5. It will print False to the Immediate Window if the variable is initialised. Once it is, its events will fire for every document.